# seemingly complex date time calculations

Tags: c++, oracle, datetime

I have this function that should convert them from Ole to UTC8601 standard, but I don't understand how the integer representations of time seem to work.

Can anyone give me some explanation?

the function is called: `RipOf_AfxTmFromOleDate`

containing statements as: `nDaysAbsolute %= 146097L;`  Where does the value come from and how is it calculated?

where `nDaysAbsolute` is a `long` type.

This app gets values from an Oracle database and sends them to another application.

Comment: My guess: it's the number of days since 1 Jan 1901.

Answer (score 2):

In 400 years, there are 97 leap years.

146097 = 365 * 400 + 97.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Julian Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Gregorian_calendar_from_Julian_day_number) calculations.